# Cucumber tests are being skipped

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber framework in my project. So for the reporting part, i need have started building the cucumber reports with jenkins.

So during the setup for the trail build i am facing the below issues.
All the tests are skipped, but not executing.
Can anyone have solution. I am happy to provide any other inputs required.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are your features located? The message states, "skip non existing resourceDirectory", so my guess would be, that he is looking for a path that is not existing.

Comment: My project structure is src/test/resources. And the control goes to src/main/resources. I have tried changing the folder structure as per the errors. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: So a local maven build on your machine works and Jenkins fails to build? Which goals are you calling, are there different profiles? What are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using maven and cucumber you have two options to run the tests.

1. With maven: mvn clean install
2. With cucumber:-Dtest=Runnerclass test
   Where Runnerclass is the class name of runner.

Answer (score 0):

Include surefire plugin in your POM.xml to pick your test. if you want to run test as well, then use mvn clean install.

Refer

[How to run Cucumber JVM Test in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553484/how-to-run-cucumber-jvm-test-in-jenkins/40488552#40488552)