# How to run Cucumber JVM Test in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have an Selenium Automation Framework integrated with Maven and Cucumber. I want to run my cucumber test using jenkins.

I am following steps to run it:

1. Create New Job > Select Maven Project
2. Provide Path of POM.xml
3. Add Post Build Action Cucumber-JVM reports
4. Save
5. Build Now

The cucumber tests are not running after executing these steps, however Build is successful.

Comment: hey Dev. Have you managed to do this. I have the same requirement and looking for proper steps.

Answer (score 2):

Your pom.xml should have runner scripted like below.

Also Goal and options in jenkins should be -**Dtest=Runnerclass test**  incase you are running single test

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>none</parallel>
                        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                        <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>Runnerclass</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

id in the above plugin is your runner.
then you can run your tests in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following libraries in your pom.xml, within

```
<pluginManagement></pluginManagement>
```

#### 1

- org.apache.maven.plugins
- maven-compiler-plugins

#### 2

- org.apache.maven.plugins
- maven-surefire-plugin

Build the project again, and then execute at the directory of your pom.xml - "maven clean", "maven test"